# How to decrypt TLS 1.2 stream going to Cloud server?

Tags: encryption, websocket, wireshark, mitmproxy

I have IOT device running on openwrt and would like to sniff traffic between IOT device application which runs and sends traffic to Cloud. Application itself uses SSL certificates as I can see in /SSL folder there is 3 certificates like Cacert.pem, newcert.pem, newkey.pem I can see that application is using websocket: Sec-WebSocket-Key: ZSKgM............ 
WebSocket-Protocol: ldc 
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13

Its possible to make decryption of traffic going towards cloud ? Certificates on IOT device is used by application and I can't replace them in easy way.....

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Have you checked out Wireshark's documentation on TLS decryption?

Comment: Yes, I have checked. What suggestions to use iot device certificates for mitm proxy?

Comment: is any way to use mitmproxy for such task ? IOT device has ca cert, cert and cert key

Comment: https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/3807#issuecomment-581648759